# Building a payment system for iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

So I’m creating an app for a guy who runs a local auction (a mini ebay meets craigslist if you will, but for more in person transactions). I’m doing it as a favor, but to also build my portfolio, so hey we both get something out of it. Now I’m running into a bit of a thinker on the “payment system”. The idea we came up with is when a seller completes the transaction, and confirms the sale, the money is held “by a middle man” until the buyer confirms the item (kind of like how Pay pal can release funds early if the buyer of an ebay item says it’s a good sale).

The client wants it set up this way so that he doesn’t miss out on his cut (10% of the sale)– as in I buy an item, meet the seller in person, then we just do an exchange there having used the app as more of a means to meet. I know Uber charges your card automatically upon GPS once you reach your destination, but it would be better to pull up the “buyer” portion of the app to confirm the sale, thus moving it from the middle man to the seller.

Aside from ensuring the client gets his cut, this can also build confidence that the “sale is funded” when the buyer is on their way.

Anyway, are there API’s out there that can help be build something like this for speedy transactions?

Not sure if this helps, but we will be using Parse as the back end.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are several payment APIs for the iOS, and I can recommend [Stripe](https://stripe.com) which has everything you need. They have an excellent support and documentation for integrating with iOS. You can check the documentation [here](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios). Also it works really well with Apple Pay and it's implementation is no brainer.

Comment: Thanks! I had stripe bookmarked from a page that recommended them, but didn't get to looking at it over the weekend. That's awesome that they come recommended.